# Make ajax call with controller and action names

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

On my MVC _layout page I have a button that drops down a panel with an iframe in it. It uses C# with Razor

I want to fill the iframe with the contents of another html page to display help for the current screen with a format like *ControllerNameActionName*Help.html.

How do I get the current Controller Name and Action Name for the Ajax call?

(Or is it the wrong way to do this?)

Comment: Are you using Razor?

Comment: Sorry I am using C# and Razor

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted or if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

you can get current page request url in c# by using various  methods.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

url of the form : http://host/controllername/methodname. then you can explode this using c#. get controller and method name segment. using this now you can send ajax call to desired controllers method.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
         url: "../ControllerName/ActionName", 
         success: function(result){
                $("#div1").html(result);
          }
         error: function(e){
          alert(e);
          }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try putting

```
<input id="IFramePath" type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")"/>
```

and in your jQuery there is no need for ajax. Just do

```
$('#myIframe').attr('src', $('#IFramePath').val());
```

**Alternative approach**

Innclude the path in the `iframe` itself

```
<iframe id="myIframe" style="display:none" src="@Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")"></iframe>
```

and show it when the button is clicked

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('#myIframe').show();
});
```

Comment: The button and frame are on the layout page so there is only 1 button and 1 frame for the entire website. Pressing the button should display the help based on the current controller/action. Your solution would require a button to be included on every view?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and answers given earlier I realised that I didn't fully understand what I needed to do when I asked the question. Sorry for that. I now realise that Ajax is not required, and I can get the values of Controller and Action from `Window.Location.href`

The Javascript/jquery I have that seems to work is shown below

```
    $('#helpButton').click(function () {
        $("#helpPanel").load(getHelpPageName());
        $("#helpPanel").animate({ height: 'toggle' }, 500);
     });

function getHelpPageName() {
    var page = "Home";

    var params = window.location.href.toString().split(window.location.host)[1];

    //remove the '/' that will be the 1st character
    params = params.substring(1);

    if (params.length == 0) {
        return page + ".html"; // no params - it's home page
    }

    var paramList = params.split('/');

    if (paramList.length === 1) //controller, no action
        page = paramList[0];
    else if (paramList.length >= 2) //controller and action - ignore rest
        page = paramList[0] + paramList[1];

    return page + ".html"; // home page - no controller, no action
}
```